# Скачать и сохранить файл по ссылке

Tags: java

есть сайт http://omc.univ.kiev.ua/ru/studentu-i-vykladachu/rozklad-zanyat/ , самая последняя ссылка - замены - http://omc.univ.kiev.ua/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B8-25.03-29.03-5.xls 
Я хочу чтобы мой телеграм бот по запросу отправлял файл, но проблема в том что я не знаю как мне автоматизировать этот процесс, ведь файл обновляется каждую неделю, а эта ссылка (замены) ведет на скачивание файла, тоесть она тоже обновляется.
Может кто-нибудь подсказать идеи?))

Answer (score 0):

Я бы предложил раз в день(час/полчаса/10 минут, как посчитаете нужным) выкачивать родительскую страницу, и из неё парсить актуальную ссылку. Существует много библиотек для парсинга HTML-страниц, например, [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/).

Причём, логично было бы обновлять ссылку на файл, только когда это нужно. То есть, получая запрос от бота, мы проверяем, актуальна ли ссылка (прошёл ли уже день/час/полчаса с её создания). Если да, то парсим новую. Если нет, то возвращаем текущую. Таким образом, ссылки не будут получаться вхолостую, когда запросов к боту нет.

Описанный выше алгоритм стремится оптимизировать количество запросов, которые делает ваше приложение, но, при низких нагрузках, можно сделать гораздо проще, и просто получать свежую ссылку каждый раз без всяких сроков действия.